# Recommendations on handling cast errors? NodeJS | MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm essentially building a form app that lets the user update their information. All the form data is stored in MongoDB. I'm also using pug templates to render my pages.

However, I'm getting some funky behavior with the code below. When I click update details on my pug template for updating, terminal shows: { CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "mylist" at path "_id" for model "Photo"

My page just keeps loading and says waiting for local host. The weird thing is when I go back to my homepage and click refresh, I see the updated details on the page and in MongoDB. Same thing goes when I try to post a new entry. I think it's because of the below specific snippets of code...

```
  router.get('/:itemid', (req, res, next)=>{
  Photo.findOne({'_id': req.params.itemid})
      .then((photo)=>{
          res.render('update', {
                item: photo
        });     
    }).catch((err)=>{
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

});

router.post('/:itemid', (req, res, next)=>{
    Photo.findOne({'_id': req.params.itemid})
        .then((photo)=>{
            var data = {
                destination: req.body.destination,
                description: req.body.description
            }
        photo.set(data);
        photo.save().then(()=>{
            res.redirect('/mylist');
        });
        }).catch((err)=>{
          if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }); 
});
```

pug template below:

```
block content
  h1 Updating Your Listing 

  .row
    .col-sm-3
      p Destination: #{item.destination} 
      p Description: #{item.description}
      img(src=item.imageurl, width="250")
      form(method='POST', action='/mylist/' + item._id)
        .form-group
          label(for='destination') Destination:
          input#name.form-control(type='text', value=item.destination 
name='destination')
        .form-group
          label(for='description') Description:
          input#email.form-control(type='text', 
value=item.description name='description')     
        button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Update Listing 
Information
```

Schema:

```
    var schema = new Schema ({
        mimetype: {type: String, required: true},
        filename: {type: String, required: true},
        imageurl: {type: String, required: true},
        description: {type: String, required: true},
        destination: {type: String, required: true},
        createdAt: {type: Date},
        updatedAt: {type: Date}
     }); 

// export models 
 module.exports = mongoose.model("Photo", schema);
```

Comment: Can you provide source code where you make POST to /:itemid? And try to `console.log(req.params)` in route handler to make sure you are passing correct id.

Comment: Thanks for helping! Sure thing,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route handler accepts `POST /:itemid`, but your form sends `POST /mylist/:itemid`. That results in express parsing mylist as your id. Change either your route to `/mylist/:itemid` or remove from your form /mylist

Comment: Aha! I got confused as later down my code, I had a redirect when first saving into the database. So i thought everything would have been relative to that. Works just fine now. Thanks so much!

res.redirect('/mylist')